# pyspark installation on windows 10 fails

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I install spark according to all available tutorials I found on internet. Set up all environmental variables yet I am still not able to launch it. Please see the attached report.[image]

Answer (score 0):

make sure your environment variables are setup properly for spark home and path, for example:

```
SPARK_HOME = D:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7
PATH += D:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin
```

Comment: yes I did. I thought maybe it is connected with Anaconda. I have python 3.8 installed and after I installed anaconda 3 distribution. As a result  I have two python installations now. Maybe it is connected to that.